# How to get Cypress.io test to wait for rendered value of div

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, cypress, chai

I have created a simple marginal tax calculator and am trying to test its functionality with Cypress. The end result of the calculator is that it displays the result amount in a div with the class of "result" to the user.

the full calculator can be viewed here: https://codepen.io/ldanneman/pen/wvdZpyV

My Cypress test returns an assertion error: "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<div.result>' to have value '18020.86', but the value was '' ".

Cypress seems to be grabbing the div before the calculated value is inserted into the div. How can i test the new value after it is rendered?

HTML

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="calculator">
  <div>
    <input class="input"/>
    <button class="submit">Calculate</button>
  </div>
  <div class="result"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Value inserted to DOM from JavaScript

```
 document.querySelector(".result").innerText = taxes
```

Cypress Test

```
describe('Marginal Calculator', () => {
    it('User Calculates Taxes', () => {
      cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html')
      cy.get('.input').type(100000)
      cy.get('.submit').click()
      cy.get('.result').should('have.value', 18020.86)
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `have.value` you have to use `have.text` if you are asserting inner text.

```js
cy.get('.result').should('have.text', '18020.86')
```

Also if you want to give some additional timeouts, you can add `{timeout: 6000}`.

```js
cy.get('.result', { timeout: 6000 }).should('have.text', '18020.86')
```